# Dramatic speed difference between PDF to PNG vs. PDF to JPEG

Tags: ghostscript, cairo, libpng, pdf-conversion, poppler

Using `pdftocairo`, on a Xeon E5-2630 (2.3GHz) CentOS 6.3 machine, poppler 0.24, cairo 1.12, libpng 1.2.49, openjpeg 1.3.10 (both CentOS default), I tested converting a 37 page PDF to convert to JPEG and PNG.  I ran `pdftocairo` with no special options (so no alpha channel for png, with density at 150ppi). The speed difference is enormous:

PDF to PNG:

```
real    0m16.858s
user    0m16.552s
sys     0m0.154s
```

That works out to about 0.43s per page.

PDF to JPEG:

```
real    0m1.762s
user    0m1.666s
sys     0m0.081s
```

Which is, well, like 10 times faster.

Now I also tested using GS to do the convert, with basically the same options, and the results are:

PDF to PNG:

```
real    0m16.500s
user    0m16.223s
sys     0m0.093s
```

Almost identical in speed to poppler, strangely.

PDF to JPEG:

```
real    0m7.468s
user    0m7.304s
sys     0m0.079s
```

Much slower than poppler, somehow, but I included this just for comparison.

Why is converting to PNG so much slower?  I need to convert them to PNGs, could there be something wrong with my libpng setups?  It's curious that GS is so much slower when converting the JPEGs but almost identical for PNGs.

Answer (score 3):

PNG compression speed is governed mostly by the zlib compression level and zlib strategy.  You trade off compression speed for compression ratio.  Compression speed is also affected to a lesser degree by the PNG filter method, "none" being the fastest and "paeth" being the slowest.  Even slower is the commonly-used "adaptive filtering" which computes a figure of merit for each of the 5 filter types and selects the best for each scanline.